# How to process list of sets having multiple element in set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, set

When I scrape websites for all the emails on each website and try to output it, I can get a given data frame which is a list of sets of multiple elements for each website:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'main_url': 'http://keilstruplund.dk', 'emails': [{'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, set(),{'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersens@hk.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'prima-rent@youseepost.dk', 'jb@rentind.dk', 'frisoren01@gmail.com', 'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'stigterndrup@gmail.com', 'psn@psn.dk', 'samuel@malerfirmaet-lykkebo.dk', 'jan@mundt-reklame.dk', 'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'nordsjalland@phonixtag.dk', 'jp@rudersdalmaleren.dk', 'vvs@hestetangen.dk', 'steenkragelund@mail.tele.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'kasserer@keilstruplund.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}]}, 
                                    {'main_url': 'http://kirsebaergaarden.com', 'emails': [{'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'soesterb@gmail.com', 'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}]},
                                     {'main_url': 'http://koglernes.dk', 'emails': [{'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'},set(), set(), {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}]},
                                      {'main_url': 'http://kongehojensbornehave.dk', 'emails': [set()]}
                                   ])
```

[image]

However, I want to process the data frame to look like the following:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'main_url': 'http://keilstruplund.dk', 'emails': ['ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk', 'prima-rent@youseepost.dk', 'jb@rentind.dk', 'frisoren01@gmail.com','stigterndrup@gmail.com', 'psn@psn.dk', 'samuel@malerfirmaet-lykkebo.dk', 'jan@mundt-reklame.dk',  'nordsjalland@phonixtag.dk', 'jp@rudersdalmaleren.dk', 'vvs@hestetangen.dk', 'steenkragelund@mail.tele.dk', 'kasserer@keilstruplund.dk']},                                        
                                     {'main_url': 'http://kirsebaergaarden.com', 'emails': ['info@kirsebaergaarden.com']},
                                     {'main_url': 'http://koglernes.dk', 'emails': ['info@koglernes.dk']},
                                      {'main_url': 'http://kongehojensbornehave.dk', 'emails': []}
                                   ])
```

[image]

How can it be achieved?

I have tried the following code but it only manage to **return first element of first set only while running to error when there is no element in the email list** for a given website:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = [', '.join(x.pop()) if not None else "" for x in URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'].values]
```

PS: As per first dataframe, I needed to get a set of multiple emails to be inserted because there can be multiple webpage for a single website and I do not want to take duplicate email from each web page.

Comment: Are you trying to end up with a distinct list of emails per url?  Why does the second record only have one email address after processing?

Comment: @Chris, yes I want to have a distinct list of emails. Also if a list has [set(), set()] or [], it should be consider as empty

Comment: if a list has [set(), set()] or [], it should be consider as empty. Also if set() is available as a value on 'emails' it just throw "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chain.from_iterable` can solve this problem.

```
from itertools import chain
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'main_url': 'http://keilstruplund.dk', 'emails': [{'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersens@hk.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'prima-rent@youseepost.dk', 'jb@rentind.dk', 'frisoren01@gmail.com', 'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'stigterndrup@gmail.com', 'psn@psn.dk', 'samuel@malerfirmaet-lykkebo.dk', 'jan@mundt-reklame.dk', 'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'nordsjalland@phonixtag.dk', 'jp@rudersdalmaleren.dk', 'vvs@hestetangen.dk', 'steenkragelund@mail.tele.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'kasserer@keilstruplund.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}]}, 
                                    {'main_url': 'http://kirsebaergaarden.com', 'emails': [{'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'soesterb@gmail.com', 'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}]},
                                     {'main_url': 'http://koglernes.dk', 'emails': [{'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}]},
                                      {'main_url': 'http://kongehojensbornehave.dk', 'emails': []}
                                   ])


URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF.emails.apply(lambda x: list(set(chain.from_iterable(x))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it serve the purpose. However, if the number of rows of the dataFrame is above 10000, can there be any faster approach or this will be performance efficient? I am running it on 10k rows now...lets see..

Comment: This should be very efficient yes.

Comment: if a list has [set(), set()] or [], it should be consider as empty. Also if set() is available as a value on 'emails' it just throw "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". Please help.

Comment: So I've answered you question, but you have more questions now.  Instead of hashing them out in the comments, why not accept my answer, then create a better question with all of your other constraints?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71881186/unable-to-process-list-of-sets-having-multiple-element-in-list-when-list-of-set 

I have created another question, so that you can answer if you have any.