# Unable to process list of sets having multiple element in list when list of set can be empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

When I scrape websites for all the emails on each website and try to output it, I can get a given data frame which is a list of sets of multiple elements for each website :

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'main_url': 'http://keilstruplund.dk', 'emails': [{'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, set(),{'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersens@hk.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'prima-rent@youseepost.dk', 'jb@rentind.dk', 'frisoren01@gmail.com', 'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'stigterndrup@gmail.com', 'psn@psn.dk', 'samuel@malerfirmaet-lykkebo.dk', 'jan@mundt-reklame.dk', 'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'nordsjalland@phonixtag.dk', 'jp@rudersdalmaleren.dk', 'vvs@hestetangen.dk', 'steenkragelund@mail.tele.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'kasserer@keilstruplund.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}, {'ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk'}]}, 
                                    {'main_url': 'http://kirsebaergaarden.com', 'emails': [{'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'soesterb@gmail.com', 'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}, {'info@kirsebaergaarden.com'}]},
                                     {'main_url': 'http://koglernes.dk', 'emails': [{'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'},set(), set(), {'info@koglernes.dk'}, {'info@koglernes.dk'}]},
                                      {'main_url': 'http://kongehojensbornehave.dk', 'emails': [set()]}
                                   ])
```

[image]

However, I want to process the data frame to  look like the following:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'main_url': 'http://keilstruplund.dk', 'emails': ['ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk', 'prima-rent@youseepost.dk', 'jb@rentind.dk', 'frisoren01@gmail.com','stigterndrup@gmail.com', 'psn@psn.dk', 'samuel@malerfirmaet-lykkebo.dk', 'jan@mundt-reklame.dk',  'nordsjalland@phonixtag.dk', 'jp@rudersdalmaleren.dk', 'vvs@hestetangen.dk', 'steenkragelund@mail.tele.dk', 'kasserer@keilstruplund.dk']},                                        
                                     {'main_url': 'http://kirsebaergaarden.com', 'emails': ['info@kirsebaergaarden.com']},
                                     {'main_url': 'http://koglernes.dk', 'emails': ['info@koglernes.dk']},
                                      {'main_url': 'http://kongehojensbornehave.dk', 'emails': []}
                                   ])
```

[image]

How can it be achieve?

I have tried the following code but it only manage to **return first element of first set only while running to error when there is no element in the email list** for a given website :

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = [', '.join(x.pop()) if not None else "" for x in URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'].values]
```

**P.S:**

1. As per the first data frame, I needed to get a set of multiple emails to be inserted because there can be multiple webpages for a single website and I do not want to take duplicate emails from each web page
2. If a list has [set(), set()] or [], it should be consider as empty. Also if set() is available as a value on 'emails' it just throw "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".
3. Thanks to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718350/chris), he provided a solution here. However, it shows error mentioned in point#2. The solution is as follows:

```
from itertools import chain
        URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF.emails.apply(lambda x: list(set(chain.from_iterable(x))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension with a set union, this should be the fastest:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = [list(set.union(*s))
                                for s in URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails']]
```

output:

```
                         main_url                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   emails
0         http://keilstruplund.dk  [ole.gregersen@hk.dk, kasserer@keilstruplund.dk, jan@mundt-reklame.dk, nordsjalland@phonixtag.dk, vvs@hestetangen.dk, ole.norlin@mail.dk, frisoren01@gmail.com, stigterndrup@gmail.com, jb@rentind.dk, psn@psn.dk, prima-rent@youseepost.dk, samuel@malerfirmaet-lykkebo.dk, steenkragelund@mail.tele.dk, jp@rudersdalmaleren.dk, ole.gregersens@hk.dk]
1     http://kirsebaergaarden.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          [soesterb@gmail.com, info@kirsebaergaarden.com]
2             http://koglernes.dk                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      [info@koglernes.dk]
3  http://kongehojensbornehave.dk                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       []
```

From a **string** that represents a list of sets:

```
from ast import literal_eval

URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = [list(set.union(*literal_eval(s)))
                                for s in URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails']]
```

or, if you have improperly formed strings, and **assuming you don't have single quotes in your email addresses**, you can use a regex:

```
import re
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = [list(set(re.findall("'([^']+@[^']+)'", s)))
                                for s in URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails']]
```

Comment: I realized my mistake and was crafting an answer just like this one.

Comment: Indeed the most concise and fastest way to do it!

Comment: @Shihab let use know how it take, but I think 17k it not so much (also depends how many items per list you have) ;)

Comment: I have failed to run it in 17k, when I try to run it on 11 rows instead, it also gives me the error on the dataframe. The dataframe can be extracted from the following [we transfer link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/997a3fc3f0476c9814a0e427a25b036a20220415081218/672c2b)

Comment: @Shihab it's because you don't have a list a sets but a string, I'll update the answer

Comment: I get the following error now:
File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ast.py", line 55, in _convert_num
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'en63@kk.dk', 'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}, {'susaet@kk.dk'}]

Comment: Thus my third option ;)

Comment: Now, I get the following error using third option, I dont understand what I am doing wrong:
File "C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 225, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I don't know, the regex option worked for me on the provided excel file

Comment: After I exported my main dataframe and run your third option on it, it works fine. Thank you for your help and I have both upvoted and accepted your answer.

Please upvote my question if you think it can be helpful to any person.

Also I have posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882673/unable-to-scrape-emails-from-some-websites-maybe-due-to-r-html-render-not-work), feel free to answer if you have any. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to combine the sets through unions and then perform your filtering when casting it into a list:

```
def combine_sets(list_of_sets):
    output = set()    
    for one_set in list_of_sets:
        output = output.union(one_set)

    # Do whatever filtering you need here
    return list(email if email is not None else '' for email in output)
```

Then your code will just be:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'].map(combine_sets)
```

Also, just a side note regarding your:

`URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'] = [', '.join(x.pop()) if not None else "" for x in URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['emails'].values]`

you are checking `if not None` which will always evaluate to True, you should be typing `if x is not None` instead.

Comment: If you meant to remove any potential `None`s, your final line in the `combine_sets` function should be `return list(email for email in output if email is not None)`